# create an array based on object keys (check if category.role has value developer)

Tags: angularjs

json object:
$scope.data = [{
    "name": "john",
    "age": "27",
    "category": {
        "id": "001",
        "role": "developer"
    }
}, {
    "name": "David",
    "age": "27",
    "category": {
        "id": "002",
        "role": "Manager"
    }
}, {
    "name": "Dave",
    "age": "27",
    "category": {
        "id": "001",
        "role": "developer"
    }
}];

Output:
{
    "developer": [{
        "name": "john",
        "age": "27",
        "category": {
            "id": "001",
            "role": "developer"
        }
    }, {
        "name": "Dave",
        "age": "27",
        "category": {
            "id": "001",
            "role": "developer"
        }
    }],
    "Manager": [{
        "name": "David",
        "age": "27",
        "category": {
            "id": "002",
            "role": "Manager"
        }
    }]
}

Comment: Post what you have done so far please. This is not a 'do my work for me' service, we'll happily help you, but not do it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really straightforward you could do something like this:

```
  angular.forEach($scope.data, function(value, key){
      if(value.category.role === "developer")
         yourObject.push(value);
   });
```

Comment: How to compare it dynamically when i dont know the role value?

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.finalData = {};
for (var i = 0, max = $scope.data.length; i < max; i++) {
if ($scope.finalData[$scope.data[i].category.role] == undefined) {
    $scope.finalData[$scope.data[i].category.role] = [];
} else {
    $scope.finalData[$scope.data[i].category.role].push($scope.data[i]);
}
}
$scope.categories = Object.keys($scope.finalData);
```

here i am pushing the complete object with category.role as key